# Why does removing a declared but not used variable causes program to terminate early?

Tags: nim-lang

I cannot figure this one out.  When I remove `let size = s.readInt64()` from the following proc, the .exe seems to terminate before it reaches the end.  It is declared but not used!  Its gotta go!

```
proc load(fn: string): Alternating =
  var s = newFileStream(fn, fmRead)
  let size = s.readInt64() #WITHOUT THIS LINE THE .exe doesn't execute ExitTerminal()
  result = newSeq[(float, int)]()
  while not s.atEnd:
    let element = (s.readFloat64.float, s.readInt64.int)
    result.add(element)
  s.close()
```

Below is the entire program.  The file type is `.dat` and I suppose it is binary.  It is created in the program.  I compiled with `-d:release` Nim version 0.18.0 and minGW compiler

```
import streams

type
  Alternating = seq[(float, int)]

proc store(fn: string, data: Alternating) =
  var s = newFileStream(fn, fmWrite)
  s.write(data.len)
  for x in data:
    s.write(x[0])
    s.write(x[1])
  s.close()

proc load(fn: string): Alternating =
  var s = newFileStream(fn, fmRead)
  let size = s.readInt64() #WITHOUT THIS LINE THE .exe doesn't execute ExitTerminal()
  result = newSeq[(float, int)]()
  while not s.atEnd:
    let element = (s.readFloat64.float, s.readInt64.int)
    result.add(element)
  s.close()


let data = @[(1.0, 1), (2.0, 2)]

store("tmp.dat", data)
let dataLoaded = load("tmp.dat")

echo dataLoaded


### EXIT PROCEDURE FROM TERMINAL PROGRAM

proc ExitTerminal: bool =
  echo "Exit Application"
  echo "(y/n)"
  while true:
    case readline(stdin)
    of "y", "Y", "yes", "Yes": return true
    of "n", "N", "no", "No": return false
    else: echo "Please be clear: yes or no"


if ExitTerminal() == false: discard ExitTerminal()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to tell because we know nothing about the file format you're reading. But generally you can't remove `s.readInt64()` just because it is unused, because apart from reading this proc advances your stream cursor. If you need to ignore the value just use `discard s.readInt64() # Ignore size`

Comment: Binary. The file is created inside the program `tmp.dat`;  I'm not really sure about advancing the stream cursor.  I don't know what or why that would be.  Can you elaborate?  Are there any other cases where I would have to declare but not use a variable in order for the program to function properly?

Comment: @JoshuaFenner, It's not the variable that can't be removed, it is the call to `readInt64` that can't be removed. Let's say your stream has the format `[size: 8bytes, a: 8bytes, b: 8bytes, size: 8bytes, a: 8bytes, b: 8bytes, ...]`. In order to read the first `a`, you have to read or skip the first `size`, in other words you have to advance your stream cursor by 8 bytes. And that's what all `read*` functions do, apart from actual reading.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.